# How to minimize the bundle size of material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, craco

I've read the [Material ui](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-2)'s article about how to `import` and `minimize` the `bundle-size`:

```js
// Option 1: instead of top level imports (without a Babel plugin):
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

// Option 2: Needs babel plugins to change below code to above code before any transformation:
import { Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
```

The problem is no matter what option I'm using, it will increase the bundle size the same amount around `100kb`!
How can we fix the problem?(I'm using craco to use the babel)